Launching Apache Superset on a work laptop with restricted rights
I tried to launch Apache Superset with docker compose up but it doesn't work. I always get the same errors:



I tried the companies tech support, but we could't figure it out either and I can't find a solution online.
So I wanted to aks if anybody knows the answer to the following questions:
**How does the detection method for NodeJs work with Apache Superset?
If we install NodeJs separately, do we need to change/configure anything on the Apache Superset or any tool we are using?
Does Apache Superset require elevated privileges to run or is it only needed for the installation?
What does Apache Superset install? **
Help would be very appreciated!
I tried setting it up the same way I did on my normal laptop.
I tried to launch and got errors concerning node.js. I deinstalled and then reinstalled node.js with the newest version, but I still can't launch Superset.
